# Smarty 3: Include same template, but from other template Set

Tags: smarty

I am working with smarty 3 and I have a default template set and I have a template set for each site for individual changes. This is how I smarty tell:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir(array('Website' => HOME . 'templates/' . $template_dir . '/', 'Default' => HOME . 'templates/default/'));
```

My default template set has a 1 col design. Now I like to create a left navigation on the home for the website.

I copy my index.tpl from default template to my second template set. This works fine.

For my new left navigation I only insert a smarty row und made an smarty include for the left navigation. I could include here the old template back for the content.

Now, I ask myself If I can include back the index.tpl from the default template to my new template.

The reson is. My new template only contains the needed construct for the left navigation. But the rest of the template would be the same. But for this include, smarty have to include index.tpl from default template. In this case smarty is not allowed to load the index.tpl from my website tmeplate.

default:index.tpl

```
%CONTENT%
```

website:index.tpl

```
%LEFT_NAVIGATIN% %CONTENT%
```

No my for website:index.tpl is

```
%LEFT_NAVIGATIN% [INCLUDE default:index.tpl]
```

As the %CONTENT% will be the same. I have include the left navigation in website:index.tpl and then include the content from default:index.tpl. Otherwise I would have to update website:index.tpl and default:index.tpl when I change something on content.

I hope my question was clear. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry the question is not clear. For all I could understand, you have two identical templates except for the left navigation and you want to use only one but for some reason you can't... is that it?

Comment: I just edit my post, I hope it is more clearly.

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question right but you can use the smarty file protokol to include templates by assoc key / "section" like `file:[Website]index.tpl`

Comment: With your update it looks clearer. so `%LEFT_NAVIGATION% {include 'file:[Default]index.tpl'}` should work. I would recommend to use template inheritance here; see: http://www.smarty.net/inheritance